# Should I replace the bent Derailleur hanger?

Tags: mountain-bike, gears, derailleur-rear

My friend (also on a bike) collided with me while we were riding together. As a result of the collision, I now have a bent derailleur hanger. Should I replace it alongside the Derailleur?

The bike is a Carrera Vengeance

[image]

Comment: Yes. You should replace it.

Comment: It's unclear what you were doing that lead to the collision, but I think you've found out that riding a MTB with no brakes is a very bad idea.

Comment: Buy a new one, straighten that one and (presuming it does not break when straightening ) keep it for emergency spare for next time you do something like this.  For daily riding it will be too weak to be reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, replace it. It's too bent to be straightened, or will be weakened considerably if it is straightened.

Comment: I have straightened hangers bent about that badly using an axle and locknut threaded into the deralier threads.  Trying to straighten it with hand tools is apt to botch it, and you have no good reference as to how straight it is (while the axle provides a good reference).